# Cookie not set (undefined) node js

Tags: node.js, cookies

I am making a `POST` request to my server and sending a token. I want to save this token into a cookie.

I have the following...

```
app.post('/saveToken', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body.token);
    res.cookie('cart', {token:req.body.token, httpOnly: true});
    console.log(req.cookies.cart);
})
```

So `req.body.token` is received. I can see it when I do `console.log`. But when I `console.log(req.cookies.cart)` I get `undefined`. I have no idea why.

I also have the following, which renders my actual app. I'm not sure if this interfering with the cookie but I will add it anyways...

```
 app.get('*', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('public/index.html'));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`req.cookies` contains the cookies that were sent with the original request.

`res.cookie()` sets a header that asks the browser to send that cookie next time, but it does not modify `req`.